# Where can I find comprehensive documentation on the various aspects of Linux?

Tags: documentation

Whenever a problem pops up in my use of Linux (full time user for 6 years) I start by googling. The simplest (or most common) issues will usually be cleared right away. If it's not in one of those two categories the advise I find tend to be wrong, misguided, obsolete, and if you ask a question here on "ask" you risk being "duplicated" to some superficially similar question.

Some issues have haunted me for years until I suddenly hit on the actual developer's documentation (or equivalent) which in a few lines explains how to solve my issue, the correct and consistent way.

Whenever that happens I'm always kicking myself: why didn't I just go here to begin with? And the obvious answer is: "I had no idea this was what I was looking for".

And for the issues that this hasn't yet happened I'm banging my head: "This ought to be either straight forward or someone tell me it's not doable"

So my question is: Are there projects out there trying to collect or list this documentation in a searchable/browseable way.

I know there are many very good "if you want this do that" tutorials on Ubuntu but I'm looking for actual documentation. That either are or could be collected in one place (at least conceptually) so that search for information could start in one place.

I'm fully aware this is a broad question but if you approach it as:

Does gnome have a comprehensive documentation project - where do I find it?

Does Ubuntu have a comprehensive documentation project - where do i find it?

For example: how *exactly* does the mime-type association work in Ubuntu and in xubuntu?

How *exactly* are menus created (in Ubuntu: quicklists, xubuntu/gnome: the main menu)

How *exactly* does the rendering process work for compiz/x? (I'm having this issue where windows randomly stops updating until somehow forced to resume (I guess). So for instance where do I look for logs that may indicate the problem. How may I change randr or other settings that may influence this issue.

So my point is to organize *exact* documentation or preferably to find projects that do this already.

Thanks!

If answers to this question get me started I'm hoping to collect such a list.

Comment: Everything is available in google.com :)

Comment: Too much to put in one question.

Comment: You write: "if you ask a question here on "ask" you risk being "duplicated" to some superficially similar question." Interesting. You could always point out how your question isn't really a duplicate.

Comment: "you could always point how your question isn't really a duplicate", of course, I would do that. But when it's already closed apparently nobody notices. It's annoying when it happens but not a big deal. "Ask" is a big site and errors are bound to happen.

Comment: @Fsando in that case you can discuss the topic on [meta] site. And I consider this question as not constructive as indicated in the [Faq#dontask] section

Comment: The topics are too broad to fit in an answer. There are several sites dealing with the topics

Comment: @a.s. I agree it's too broad and now well thought out. Should I delete it?

Comment: @Fsando I think you cannot delete it now, since it has an answer. You can vote it to close if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/  is the "Official Documentation" page for Ubuntu 12.04. This breaks into further subcategoies. Additional documentation, including the various releases can also be found at http://help.ubuntu.com .

Comment: Each individual project can, and often does, have separate documentation sites.